# Differentiate document sets based on fields and its types in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

Consider i have following type of data in MongoDB

```
"_id" : 34432143, "A" : "ath1", "B" : 100, "C" : "name1"  
"_id" : 34432154, "A" : "ath2", "B" : 101, "C" : "name2"  
"_id" : 34432168, "A" : "ath3", "B" : 102, "C" : "name3"


"_id" : 34432171, "A" : 1, "B" : "class1", "C" : 21

"_id" : 34432174, "A" : 2, "B" : "class2", "C" : 22

"_id" : 34432178, "A" : 3, "B" : "class3", "C" : 23
```

Here we can see that in first set A is String, B is Integer and C is String 
and in second set we can observe  A is Integer, B is String and C is Integer

Can I identify that there are two sets of records and differentiate that, in first set there are A,B,C fields with data types String, Integer, String. In second set there are A,B,C fields with data types Integer, String, Integer.

Comment: Can you influence how the documents are stored? In that case you should maybe use two different MongoDB collections, each for one type of document instead.

Comment: Look into using a $group, with a projection of $type of the field.